# Splitting dataframe into multiple dataframes in Scala Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have below JSON file(details) in hadoop. I am able to read this file from hd fs by using SQL Context read json. Then want to split the file into number of files depending on the date and add date to file name (there can be any number of dates in file).

input file Name : details

```
{"Name": "Pam", "Address": "", "Gender":"F", "Date": "2019-09-27 06:47:57"}
{"Name": "David", "Address": "", "Gender":"M", "Date": "2019-09-27 10:47:56"}
{"Name": "Mike", "Address": "", "Gender":"M", "Date": "2019-09-26 08:48:57"}
```

expected output files:

file Name 1 : details_20190927

```
{"Name": "Pam", "Address": "", "Gender":"F", "Date": "2019-09-27 06:47:57"}
{"Name": "David", "Address": "", "Gender":"M", "Date": "2019-09-27 10:47:56"}
```

file Name 2 : details_20190926

```
{"Name": "Mike", "Address": "", "Gender":"M", "Date": "2019-09-26 08:48:57"}
```

Comment: Parse Date field to a format that you want to split  2019-09-27 06:47:57 to details_20190927 to a new column lets say filename. Then apply partition by filename before persisting dataframe to any filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The paths won't be exactly as you have specified them, but you can write the records on different files like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._;
import spark.implicits._

val parsed = spark.read.json("details.json")
val repartitioned = parsed.repartition(col("Date"))
val withPartitionValue = parsed.withColumn("PartitionValue", date_format(col("Date"),"yyyyMMdd"))
withPartitionValue.write.partitionBy("PartitionValue").json("/my/output/folder")
```

Comment: Thanks For the help. Code which you gave is creating partitions under one folder because we are saving one dataframe based on partitions how can i get each partition into individual dataframes. Beacuse i have multiple files with different dates and i need to store under one folder.

Comment: @kumark I guess that you will have to move the files with other code which is not Spark code.